# PHP Echo File Contents With Control

Tags: php, file, show

Firstifully I'm very new to php. I'm trying to show a text file's content with php. But it will check the user ip. If Ip is equals to my ip it will show to file. I used this code:

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents( "example.txt" ); 
?>
```

But I need to hide the example.txt . So noone can go to example.txt and display the content.
Thanks

Comment: Where are you checking for IP?

Comment: what you exactly want? hide the text file from direct access or don't want to show the file_get_content() value to others?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108399/deny-access-to-specific-file-types-in-specific-directory

Answer (score 1):

```
<Files example.txt>
    Order Deny,Allow 
    Allow from server.ip.xxx.xxxx 127.0.0.1
    Deny from all
</Files>
```

Add it to your `.htaccess` file.

that should do it

Comment: OP is not expecting doing this with `.htaccess`

Comment: This is valid, but the OP tagged this question as `php`. You should suggest a php solution. I upvoted anyway, but please be careful about the tags next time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == "MYIP")
{
  echo file_get_contents( "example.txt" );
}
```

replace MYIP with your IP for example : 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
<?php
/**
 * Try and get the client's IP address.
 */
function getClientIPAddress() {
    $ip;
    if (getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP"))
        $ip = getenv("HTTP_CLIENT_IP");
    else if (getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"))
        $ip = getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
    else if (getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"))
        $ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
    else
        $ip = "UNKNOWN";
    return $ip;
}

$myIpAddress = "10.1.1.1"; // Your IP Address
$filename = "example.txt"; // file to get contents

if(getClientIPAddress() === $myIpAddress) {
    echo file_get_contents( $filename  ); 
}
else {
    echo "You are not authorized to see the contents of '$filename'";
}
```