# How to allow download just .zip and exe [Laravel 5.1]

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-validation

How can I allow that user be able just to download `zip` and `exe` files?

I am currently use this function:

```
public function download($id)
    {
        $headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-msdownload',
            'Content-Type: application/zip'
        );

        return response()->download(storage_path() . '/app/' . 'gamers.png', 'gamers.png', $headers);
    }
```

And this allow me download any file, how can I limit it just on zip and exe?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send a response so the headers mean only that browser will understand you are sending a file of type Content-Type application/x-msdownload or application/zip.  To limit the files from server directly you can try limiting the directory using .htaccess file and in the code you get the $id probably you could get the file object or details of the file(if you have any) and check its type before sending the response.

Example for limiting access to files in folder with extension 
[Deny access to specific file types in specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108399/deny-access-to-specific-file-types-in-specific-directory)

you can customize the above as per your needs

Comment: Here is a example with .htaccess (note works only if you server is apache based )based limitations 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108399/deny-access-to-specific-file-types-in-specific-directory

Comment: Here is the path `storage_path() . '/app/' . 'gamers.png'` which I need to validate

Comment: I assume you are using laravel. https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#files
may be go through this. it may give you some idea.