# .htaccess to allow only pdf files in a subdirectory

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to write an `.htaccess` file to only allow access to pdf files in a subdirectory. I'm going to deploy the file on a host that I don't control, so I can't make changes to the apache configuration.

I want to only allow access to .pdf files in the `Foo` directory. I have attempted:

```
Deny From All

<FilesMatch ".+\/Foo\/.+\.pdf$">
Allow From All
</FilesMatch>
```

However, when I attempt to access `example.com/bar/Foo/baz.pdf`, I am given an HTTP 403 Forbidden response.

How can I deny access to everything, except for pdf files in one particular directory?

Thanks

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this: [Deny Access to Specific File Types in Specific Directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108399/deny-access-to-specific-file-types-in-specific-directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a this inside root .htaccess as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

# prohibit everything except .pdf files    
RewriteRule ^foo/(?!.*\.pdf$) - [F,NC]
```

Comment: That would work, but I'd prefer not put it in the subdirectory. How could I expand the regex? I've tried `!^.+\/Foo\/.+\.pdf$`, but it hasn't worked for me.

Comment: I think I get it now. What I was trying to get was `RewriteRule !^Foo\/.+\.pdf$ - [F,NC]`. Thanks!

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help