# How can i deny direct access from url to all php file and some html in my server folder using htaccess?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I'm trying to hide all the php and some html file in my server folder only by direct call from url... particularly i need to hide the register.html (this file is for users registration), and other php file.. (these php files contain sensitive data for database connection). How can i do this?? Thanks for any help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create/edit the *.htaccess* file in the directory where the files are located.

For denying all direct access to **all files in the directory**, add this:

```
Deny from all
```

For restricting **only a specific file**:

```
<Files "register.html">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

For restricting **specific file types**, you need to edit the .htaccess file in the webroot folder. This rule will deny access to all *.php* and *.html* files in *myFolder* and its subdirectories.:

```
RewriteRule ^myFolder/.*\.(php|html)$ - [F,L,NC]
```

More examples on denying access to file types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20489058/6817376

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for `register.html`:

```
<Files "register.html">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

and in the same way for other files.