# Prevent Downloading PHP File

Tags: php

I use this code to direct access to my php files. It works perfectly, when somebody try to access this file, it forwards them to error.php. But when I download php file with IDM or other downloader, output of ECHO function can be downloaded. How can I prevent downloading a php file output? My codes :

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    header('location:http://www.sitename.com/error.php');

    exit;

}


echo "  
XXXXXXX
";

?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'works perfectly', 'access', 'download'.  Please state what happens under specific scenarios, and how that changes from what you desire/expect, and tell us what that is.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a more detailed description of what you want to do or what you want to prevent.

Comment: I have edited my question. @Progrock can you please tell me if there is any other way?

Answer (score 1):

You can put your php files outside your public html folder. Then you can include them like usual on the ones that you allow to access.

Another option is to use [.htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108399/deny-access-to-specific-file-types-in-specific-directory)