# how to limit access to txt files ONLY for the web server using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a folder containing some php files (php) and some text files (txt).
The php files are forms and they read/write the text files.

I would like to setup an htaccess files which allows the access of the txt files ONLY for the php files (i.e. the "server") and NOT for the visitors of the web site (http).

I ve tried the following without success:
.htaccess files placed in the folder containing the txt and the php files
`<Files *.txt> deny from all allow from localhost </Files>`

Does anyone may have suggestions ?

Francis

Comment: Another more secure solution would be to create all txt file outside the public folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deny access to specific file types in specific directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16108399/deny-access-to-specific-file-types-in-specific-directory)

Comment: As already noted, PHP can (and should) manipulate the files *.txt right from the file system, so there's no need to publish them in the first place and there's no need to grant permissions to PHP (since it isn't using the web server anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `order` your `allow` and `deny` commands

```
<files *.txt>
Order allow/deny
Allow from localhost
Deny from all
</files>
```

You can also use `mod-rewrite` to protect your `.txt` files it's faster  then the `allow/deny` directive

```
 RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule \.txt$ - [F]
```

This will return a `forbidden` error for your .txt files if you access them using `http` .

Comment: thanks all for your answers. I found out the following to be more portable (and working): <FilesMatch "\.(?:txt)$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>